# CSS not being applied to rendered page but shows in IDE

Tags: css, visual-studio, asp.net-membership

**Visual Studio 2008 - ASP Membership Login control**

I'm trying to style the ASP:Login control.  I've converted it to a Template - here's the markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="My.Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>My Login</title>
    <link href="Style.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" 
                    style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="normalAAText" align="center" colspan="2">
                                        Log In</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName" CssClass="normalAAText" >User Name:</asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" CssClass="normalAAText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                            ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." 
                                            ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right" class="normalAAText">
                                        <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password" CssClass="normalAAText">Password:</asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                            ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." 
                                            ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe"  CssClass="normalAAText" runat="server" Text="Remember me next time." />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                        <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" 
                                            ValidationGroup="Login1" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:Login>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the IDE the page looks like this:

[image]

However, when it's rendered it looks like this (i.e. no styling)

[image]

I can apply stying in-line for each control, but that rather defeats the object of a style sheet.  It's clear that the CSS file is correctly linked otherwise the IDE wouldn't display my nice purple lettering!

Any thoughts?

The CSS file is below.  Thanks

Edward

```
body
{
}
.grid-view
{
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS","lucida grande","Segoe UI",arial,verdana,"lucida sans unicode",tahoma,sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.grid-view tr.header
{
    background-color: #ADB0FF;
    border-bottom: "1px solid #000";
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS","lucida grande","Segoe UI",arial,verdana,"lucida sans unicode",tahoma,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}

.normalAAText
{
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS","lucida grande","Segoe UI",arial,verdana,"lucida sans unicode",tahoma,sans-serif;
    color: #6666cc;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.header
{
    background-color    :#ADB0FF
}

.linkButton
{
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS","lucida grande","Segoe UI",arial,verdana,"lucida sans unicode",tahoma,sans-serif;
    color: Red;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.grid-view tr.normal
{
    background-color :#CECCFF; 
    border-bottom:"0px solid #000"; COLOR: #000000; 
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS","lucida grande","Segoe UI",arial,verdana,"lucida sans unicode",tahoma,sans-serif;
    FONT-SIZE:12px; TEXT-DECORATION: none; height:17px;
}

.grid-view tr.alternate
{
     background-color:#A0A0FF; border-bottom:"1px solid #000"; COLOR: #000000; 
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS","lucida grande","Segoe UI",arial,verdana,"lucida sans unicode",tahoma,sans-serif;
     FONT-SIZE: 12px; height:17px; TEXT-DECORATION: none ;  
}

.grid-view tr.normal:hover, .grid-view tr.alternate:hover
{
    background-color :#BDDFF8; border-bottom:"0px solid #000"; COLOR: #000000; 
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS","lucida grande","Segoe UI",arial,verdana,"lucida sans unicode",tahoma,sans-serif; FONT-SIZE:12px; TEXT-DECORATION: none; height:17px;
}
 .btnSaveCancel
{
    border-color: #B3CCE6;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS","lucida grande","Segoe UI",arial,verdana,"lucida sans unicode",tahoma,sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-bottom-style: double;
    border-left-style: double;
    border-right-style: groove;
    border-top-style: groove;
    border-bottom-width: 1;
    border-left-width: 1;
    border-right-width: 1;
    border-top-width: 1;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: hand;
    color: #000000;

}

a.logout
{
    padding: 2px 5px;
    color: #ffffff;FONT-SIZE: 12px; 
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS","lucida grande","Segoe UI",arial,verdana,"lucida sans unicode",tahoma,sans-serif;
}
a.logout:visited
{
    padding: 2px 5px;
    color: #ffffff;FONT-SIZE: 12px; 
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS","lucida grande","Segoe UI",arial,verdana,"lucida sans unicode",tahoma,sans-serif;
}

a.logout:hover
{
    padding: 2px 5px;
    color: #ffffff;FONT-SIZE: 12px; 
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS","lucida grande","Segoe UI",arial,verdana,"lucida sans unicode",tahoma,sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague has explained to me that the style sheet is a protected asset, which cannot be loaded until authentication.  I've moved it into a folder for which anonymous access is permitted, and all works well.